# How to make arc text effect in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, typography, illustration

I'm wondering how can I achieve such an effect in Illustrator or Photoshop. I think that part of the trick is to place text on arc, but then you also need to give it a little bit of perspective, like the text is coming from afar, and it kind of rotated a little bit. Sample below.

[image: text sample]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The same as Lucian's answer but with a trick:

[image: arch]

Group the text with a *dummy shape* before applying the Warp:

[image: Group]

Selecting the shape with the **Direct Selection Tool** > fill color none, stroke color none

[image: dummy color none]

Adjust the distortion moving the shape:

[image: control]

The text is still editable:

[image: editable text]

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways. This one is for Illustrator.

1. Type some text, and select it
2. Click *Object > Envelope > Make with Mesh*
3. Set the Mesh options to 1 row, and 1 column
4. Then with the Direct Selection tool, edit the anchors and curves to bend the text as required.

[image]

You can even go a bit crazy with the curves!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

1. With your text object selected, go to 'Object → Envelope Distort → Make with Warp' or just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.
2. Play with the 'Arc' or 'Arch' settings until it looks about right.

[image]